No cambiar la imagen en html desde javascript
Intento hacer un juego de blackjack pero el problema es que se remplaza la primer img en todos los jugadores, en lugar de que la carta 1 se ponga en el img de ID "carta1" y la carta 2 se ponga en el img de ID "carta2", lo mismo con todos los demas jugadores
Intento cambiar las imagenes de las siguientes  lineas:
<label>Tus cartas:</label>
        <img src="Img/Cartas/Corazones/14CO.png" id="carta1">
        <img src="Img/Cartas/Corazones/14CO.png" id="carta2">
        <img src="Img/Cartas/Corazones/14CO.png" id="carta3">
        <img src="Img/Cartas/Corazones/14CO.png" id="carta4">
        <img src="Img/Cartas/Corazones/Blanco.jpg" id="carta5">
        <img src="Img/Cartas/Corazones/Blanco.jpg" id="carta6">
<label>Cartas jugador 2:</label>
        <img src="Img/Cartas/Corazones/14CO.png" id="carta1J2">
        <img src="Img/Cartas/Corazones/14CO.png" id="carta2J2">
        <img src="Img/Cartas/Corazones/14CO.png" id="carta3J2">
        <img src="Img/Cartas/Corazones/14CO.png" id="carta4J2">
        <img src="Img/Cartas/Corazones/Blanco.jpg" id="carta5J2">
        <img src="Img/Cartas/Corazones/Blanco.jpg" id="carta6J2">


Asi como en las cartas del jugador 2 hay un codigo muy parecido, solo remplazas  el J2 por un J3,J4 y 4D al final del ID
Codigo Javascript:
conta1=1;
conta2=1;
conta3=1;
conta4=1;
conta5=1;
Img1=document.getElementById("carta"+conta1);
Img2=document.getElementById("carta"+conta2+"J2");
Img3=document.getElementById("carta"+conta3+"J3");
Img4=document.getElementById("carta"+conta4+"J4");
Img5=document.getElementById("carta"+conta5+"D");
conta1=0;
conta1=conta1+1;
conta2=0;
conta3=0;
conta4=0;
conta5=0;
function selecarta(argument) {
                        S=0;
                        switch (cartas[i]) {
                            case 0:
                                S=1;
                                if (PC==1) {
                                    TM=TM+1;
                                    conta1=conta1+1;
                                    Img1.src="Img/Cartas/"+"Corazones/"+S+"CO.png";
                                }
                                if (PC==2) {
                                    MJ2=MJ2+1;
                                    conta2=conta2+1;
                                    Img2.src="Img/Cartas/"+"Corazones/"+S+"CO.png";
                                }
                                if (PC==3) {
                                    MJ3=MJ3+1;
                                    conta3=conta3+1;
                                    Img3.src="Img/Cartas/"+"Corazones/"+S+"CO.png";
                                }
                                if (PC==4) {
                                    MJ4=MJ4+1;
                                    conta4=conta4+1;
                                    Img4.src="Img/Cartas/"+"Corazones/"+S+"CO.png";
                                }
                                if (PC==5) {
                                    MD=MD+1;
                                    conta5=conta5+1;
                                    Img5.src="Img/Cartas/"+"Corazones/"+S+"CO.png";
                                }
                            break;

Así sigue sucesivamente hasta el caso 51, y si asigna la carta que es, en eso no hay problema

Como se puede ver, la segunda carta no cambia, y la imagen que aparece en la primer carta no corresponde a lo que se muestra en la consola, la carta que aparece en la imagen es la segunda carta, y pues deberia ir en el espacio de la carta 2. El problema no es que reparta las cartas incorrectamente, eso si esta bien, el unico problema son las imagenes

Si quieren puedo mandar el codigo completo al privado, solo que son mas de 1000 lineas

Saludos. A mi pensar (y como idea); lo idóneo es que recibieras un maso de cartas las barajes y este maso de cartas bajaradas es el orden en que las repartes; ya sea que las extraigas de arriba o de abajo del maso; de esa forma (por lo que entiendo te ocurre) evitas dar la misma carta a más de un jugador. Ya que del maso extraes una carta y entregas al jugador.

Si hago eso hermano, este es el codigo:
while(cartas.length<52){     cartasP=Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);     if (!cartas.includes(cartasP)) {      cartas.push(cartasP);     }    } 
Y ese no es el problema, las cartas se reparten bien, no se repiten y si da las cartas correctas, el problema es que la imagen del html no se remplaza corectamente, siempre se remplaza la Imagen 1, independientemente del jugador

Saludos de nuevo. En tu código hace falta saber si i la incrementas siempre y no la inicializas por cada jugador a que repartes;... lo correcto es que una vez que das la carta a un jugador la saques del maso y así siempre tomas el primer elemento, o si siempre tomas el elemento cartas[i] tu variable i solo debe inicializarse una vez e de ahí solo incrementarse (sin inicializar cada vez que repartes a otro jugador).

No puse el codigo completo, segun yo si lo hago, te lo puedo mandar al privado por discord,whatsapp o algo parecido?

Entiendo el problema. Estás usando las mismas variables Img1, Img2, Img3, etc. para todos los jugadores, por eso se sobreescribe la imagen en la primera. Necesitas crear variables separadas para cada imagen de cada jugador.
Aquí te muestro cómo puedes solucionar esto:
    // Inicializar contadores para cada jugador
let conta1 = 1;
let conta2 = 1;
let conta3 = 1;
let conta4 = 1;
let conta5 = 1;

// Obtener las imágenes de cada jugador como un array
let Img1 = [document.getElementById("carta" + conta1), document.getElementById("carta" + (conta1 + 1))];
let Img2 = [document.getElementById("carta" + conta2 + "J2"), document.getElementById("carta" + (conta2 + 1) + "J2")];
let Img3 = [document.getElementById("carta" + conta3 + "J3"), document.getElementById("carta" + (conta3 + 1) + "J3")];
let Img4 = [document.getElementById("carta" + conta4 + "J4"), document.getElementById("carta" + (conta4 + 1) + "J4")];
let Img5 = [document.getElementById("carta" + conta5 + "D"), document.getElementById("carta" + (conta5 + 1) + "D")];

// ... (resto de tu código)

function selecarta(argument) {
  S = 0;
  switch (cartas[i]) {
    case 0:
      S = 1;
      if (PC == 1) {
        TM = TM + 1;
        conta1 = conta1 + 1;
        // Actualiza la imagen según el contador
        Img1[conta1 - 1].src = "Img/Cartas/" + "Corazones/" + S + "CO.png"; 
      } else if (PC == 2) {
        MJ2 = MJ2 + 1;
        conta2 = conta2 + 1;
        Img2[conta2 - 1].src = "Img/Cartas/" + "Corazones/" + S + "CO.png";
      } else if (PC == 3) {
        MJ3 = MJ3 + 1;
        conta3 = conta3 + 1;
        Img3[conta3 - 1].src = "Img/Cartas/" + "Corazones/" + S + "CO.png";
      } else if (PC == 4) {
        MJ4 = MJ4 + 1;
        conta4 = conta4 + 1;
        Img4[conta4 - 1].src = "Img/Cartas/" + "Corazones/" + S + "CO.png";
      } else if (PC == 5) {
        MD = MD + 1;
        conta5 = conta5 + 1;
        Img5[conta5 - 1].src = "Img/Cartas/" + "Corazones/" + S + "CO.png";
      }
      break;
    // ... (casos restantes)
  }
}

Explicación de los cambios:
Arrays para las imágenes: Ahora tenemos arrays Img1, Img2, etc., donde cada elemento del array representa una imagen.
Actualización de imágenes específicas: En lugar de usar una sola variable, ahora usamos Img[conta - 1].src para actualizar la imagen correcta dentro del array.
Con este código, la segunda carta debería mostrarse correctamente en la segunda imagen de cada jugador, y no se debería sobreescribir la primera.
Recuerda:
Contadores: Asegúrate de que los contadores conta1, conta2, etc., se incrementen correctamente para que se use la imagen correcta.
Ids de las imágenes: Los IDs de las imágenes deben ser diferentes para cada jugador, y seguir una lógica coherente (por ejemplo, carta1, carta2, carta1J2, carta2J2, etc.).

Hermano la verdad no entendí que le cambiaste al código, según yo es lo mismo, aparte de que lo cambie y no soluciono. Ya agregué mas información a la pregunta original, a ver si se entiende mas el problema

Intenta con la modificacion cambiando o generando los ARRAY, para mi el error esta en el manejo de esas variables, evidentemente no estas mostrando todo el codigo por ello es mas complejo implementar la solucion a simple vista

Te puedo mandar el codigo por privado? Ya sea en WhatsApp o discord o algo así?
